# troubles creating regex expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a measure device that creates samples in the following format:

`V  GL020(1)=20110117161703`

another example:

`V  GLXX011(10)=ADEF=*GFSDAS`

What I'm trying to do is to create a regex expression that returns 
`GL020 / 1 / 20110117161703` for the first example and
`GLXX011 / 10 / ADEF=*GFSDAS` for the second example.

I found a regex expression that reliably matches the fist two required parts:

`.*?(?<Field>(?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*)).*?(?<Count>\d+)`

However, i'm still missing the part after the first `"="`. I don't know if it is important but the part after the first `"="` might include characters like `"="` itself.

Comment: You're having trouble matching everything after the equals-sign? Then match against exactly one equals-sign + everything that follows (which would include more equals-signs of course)

Comment: Couldn't you just skip the first two characters (`V `) and replace `(` and `)=` with ` / ` (and if it matters, just their first occurrences)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an expression like:

```
(\w+)\((\d+)\)=(\S+)
```

Giving you the substrings that you want in the first, second and third capturing groups.

Comment: lol. wow. so easy. i spent hours on that one. :((. thank you very much. the third capturing group might include spaces as well. how would i handle that?

Comment: @lightxx, if you just want to capture everything after the first `=`, you could change `\S+` to `.+`. (`.` does not match new lines unless you use the `s` flag.)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this one:

```
([^\(|\s]+)\((\d+)\)=([\w|\=|\*]+)
```

Comment: @Qtax it was quicker to add here a newline in the answer than to explain in a comment, what should be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

please use this regex:

```
(?<first>\w+)\s(?<second>\w+)(?<third>\(\d+\))=(?<forth>.*)
```